# Minimization of positive quadratic function using gradient descent in at most $ n $ steps

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

For minimization positive quadratic form $$f = \frac{1}{2}\left\langle Ax,x \right\rangle - \left\langle b,x\right\rangle \rightarrow \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n},$$ we use gradient descent  $$x^{k+1} = x^{k} - \alpha_k \nabla f(x^k)$$ with step $\alpha_k = \frac{1}{\lambda_{k+1}}$ , where $\lambda_{k+1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ $(0 < \mu = \lambda_1 \leqslant \cdots \leqslant \lambda_n = L)$. I need to prove that $x^n = x^*$, where $Ax^* = b$.

---

I have an idea, that I need to go to basis, where $A$ becomes diagonal, $A = P^T \Lambda P$, where $\Lambda = \text{diag} \{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \}$ and $P$ consists of eigenvectors.
I tried to  express $x^* - x^0$ and $x^n - x^0$ as a linear combination of basis vectors to compare them, but didn't succeed. Could you please help me with that proof?

Comment: You mean that $x^n \to x^*$ with $Ax^*=b$? But you cannot really assume $Ax=b$ even has an exact solution, so what is $x^*$?

Comment: @gt6989b it's stated that $x^*$ is the solution of $Ax=b$. And I need to prove that $x^* = x^n$ exactly. So this method is finite.

Comment: could you show your attempt in more detail?

Comment: @LinAlg okay. $\nabla f(x) = Ax - b$ -- gradient.  In basis of eigenvectors $x^* - x^0 = \sum \limits^N_{k=1}\beta_k p_k \Rightarrow \beta_k \dfrac{p^T_k\Lambda(x^* - x_0)}{p^T_k\Lambda p_k} $. 
And $x^N - x^0 = - \sum \limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \dfrac{\Lambda x^i - P^Tb}{\lambda_{i+1}}$. So they look a bit same, cause $p^T_k \Lambda p_k = \lambda_k$. Then I tried to express $x^N - x^0$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors using scalar multiplication, but without success. I need to show somehow that numerators are equal, but i don't know how. 
Also tried to solve by simple substitution.

Comment: Try to get some inspiration form Conjugate Gradient - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method.

Comment: @Royi, thank you, already saw it and thought about that. But still don't know the solution. As you see, I tried to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume that you have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors so that $A$ is
diagonal, with the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ on the diagonal. Let me use $\Lambda$
for $A$ in this basis, just for emphasis.

Note that the solution is given by $x^*= \Lambda^{-1} b$.

Then $x_{k+1} = x_k -{1 \over \lambda_{k+1}} (\Lambda x_k -b) = (I-{1 \over \lambda_{k+1}} \Lambda) x_k + {1 \over \lambda_{k+1}} b$, for $k=0,...,n-1$.

Note that the $k+1$th entry of $x_{k+1}$ satisfies $[x_{k+1}]_{k+1} = 0 + [x^*]_{k+1}$, and if $[x_k]_i = [x^*]_i$ for $i=0,...,k$, then 
$[x_{k+1}]_i = [x^*]_i$ for $i=0,...,k$.

Hence $x_n = x^*$.

Comment: Thank you, did the same thing according to plan in previous comment.

Comment: What previous comment & plan are you talking about?

Comment: about Royi's answer

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked this but this is the sketch of the proof I think you should do:

1. Build the solution using the matrix eigen vectors.
2. Show that in each step you update only single coordinate which matches the solution of 1 while leaving others as they are.
3. Conclude that after $ n $ steps there are no direction to minimize along hence the point is optimal.

I think you should state that $ A $ is [Positive (Semi) Definite Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I proved  according to your plan. Hope that I did it right :)

Comment: So please mark it as answer and add your full steps for others to see.

Comment: The directions that the algorithm takes are not necessarily orthogonal.

Comment: @copper.hat, Actually this is what I thought was the pitfall of my idea.  BibaJackson, you should mark copper.hat answer as the right one.